# Using Cassandra with Spring boot gradle. Which API to use to connect?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, apache-kafka, datastax

Hi I am starting a new **Spring Boot** project using Cassandra.
I am doing my study on it but I have some doubt on the below issues:

1. Using Spring Boot, which would be the best API for connecting to Cassandra ?
   Eg:Datstax or Astyanax ? Are Datastax and CQL3 different ?
   (As of now some '13 answers have a rift between Datastax and Astyanax. Its inconclusive.)
2. Is Python required to run Cassandra ?
3. Where can I get good reading material on Cassandra ? And its usage/integration with Spring/Spring Boot

Also, going forward we will be integrating Apache Kafka with this project.
I have gone through some old answers, but the are 5 years old. So I am looking for a more concluding answer.

Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot has native support for Datastax driver with spring-data.
Easy way to start is to check my sample apps: 
http://valchkou.com/spring-boot-cassandra.html

Spring Data Cassandra Documentation
https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/

The best Cassandra Documentation provided by Datastax. 
Python is not required to run cassandra. 
JRE 8 is required.

Spring Boot has support for kafka.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: I have JDK 8, but to run cql commands it asked for Python. I must have done something wrong.

Comment: Also, can we create tables in Cassandra using entity class and @Table annotation ? Or do we have to write scripts for creating namespaces and tables ?

Comment: Currently spring-boot does not support it. You have to create script manually

Answer (score -1):

You could have lot of documentation on
Apache Cassandra documentation
Docs.datatstax.com